# Delphi Berlin Rest interface POST behavior wrong

Tags: rest, delphi, redirect, post

## After upgrading from Delphi XE10 Seattle to Berlin, my REST interface does no longer work properly.

#### The POST request returns a 302 FOUND redirect.

In Seattle, a new POST to the redirected url is issued, and the resource is created.

In Berlin, the 302 FOUND is answered with a GET, resulting in a list of existing resources being returned i.s.o. the id.

network trace :

#### SEATTLE

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  1 0.000000       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      66     62766→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
  2 0.019867       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      66     80→62766 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
  3 0.020024       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62766→80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
  4 0.032015       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         HTTP/XML 920    POST /api/specific_price_rules/?ws_key=_______MY_SECRET_WEB_KEY________ HTTP/1.1 
  5 0.049632       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→62766 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=867 Win=7680 Len=0
  6 0.278089       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          HTTP     407    HTTP/1.0 302 Found 
  7 0.278426       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→62766 [FIN, ACK] Seq=354 Ack=867 Win=7680 Len=0
  8 0.278480       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62766→80 [ACK] Seq=867 Ack=354 Win=66304 Len=0
  9 0.279197       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62766→80 [ACK] Seq=867 Ack=355 Win=66304 Len=0
 10 0.279327       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62766→80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=867 Ack=355 Win=66304 Len=0
 11 0.282931       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      66     62767→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
 12 0.303173       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→62766 [ACK] Seq=355 Ack=868 Win=7680 Len=0
 13 0.303307       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      66     80→62767 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 14 0.303416       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62767→80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
 15 0.329188       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         HTTP/XML 984    POST /api/specific_price_rules/?ws_key=_______MY_SECRET_WEB_KEY________?url=specific_price_rules%2F&ws_key=_______MY_SECRET_WEB_KEY________ HTTP/1.1 
 16 0.346802       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→62767 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=931 Win=7808 Len=0
 17 0.772415       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          HTTP/XML 1193   HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
 18 0.823564       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62767→80 [ACK] Seq=931 Ack=1140 Win=65536 Len=0
 19 2.792272       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→62767 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1140 Ack=931 Win=7808 Len=0
 20 2.792381       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62767→80 [ACK] Seq=931 Ack=1141 Win=65536 Len=0
 21 2.792460       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     62767→80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=931 Ack=1141 Win=65536 Len=0
 22 2.809253       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→62767 [ACK] Seq=1141 Ack=932 Win=7808 Len=0
```

#### BERLIN

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  1 0.000000       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      66     50854→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
  2 0.028660       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      66     80→50854 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
  3 0.028816       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50854→80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
  4 0.159076       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         HTTP/XML 920    POST /api/specific_price_rules/?ws_key=_______MY_SECRET_WEB_KEY________ HTTP/1.1 
  5 0.177091       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→50854 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=867 Win=7680 Len=0
  6 0.252763       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          HTTP     407    HTTP/1.0 302 Found 
  7 0.252764       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→50854 [FIN, ACK] Seq=354 Ack=867 Win=7680 Len=0
  8 0.253495       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50854→80 [ACK] Seq=867 Ack=355 Win=66304 Len=0
  9 0.253633       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50854→80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=867 Ack=355 Win=66304 Len=0
 10 0.256926       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      66     50857→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
 11 0.270249       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→50854 [ACK] Seq=355 Ack=868 Win=7680 Len=0
 12 0.274200       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      66     80→50857 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
 13 0.274327       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50857→80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
 14 0.277184       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         HTTP     423    GET /api/specific_price_rules/?ws_key=_______MY_SECRET_WEB_KEY________?url=specific_price_rules%2F&ws_key=_______MY_SECRET_WEB_KEY________ HTTP/1.1 
 15 0.294220       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→50857 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=370 Win=6912 Len=0
 16 0.511007       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          HTTP/XML 597    HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 17 0.561407       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50857→80 [ACK] Seq=370 Ack=544 Win=66048 Len=0
 18 2.510340       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→50857 [FIN, ACK] Seq=544 Ack=370 Win=6912 Len=0
 19 2.510429       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50857→80 [ACK] Seq=370 Ack=545 Win=66048 Len=0
 20 2.510533       192.168.1.99          159.253.0.125         TCP      54     50857→80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=370 Ack=545 Win=66048 Len=0
 21 2.526591       159.253.0.125         192.168.1.99          TCP      60     80→50857 [ACK] Seq=545 Ack=371 Win=6912 Len=0
```

#### Sample code

```
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aNode, aCNode, aCCNode: IXMLNode;
  i, j: integer;
  aXml, s: string;
begin
  Button8.Enabled := False;
  try
    RESTRequest1.ResetToDefaults;
    RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
    RESTClient1.BaseURL := sWebAddress;
    RESTRequest1.Resource := Edit1.Text;
    RESTClient1.Authenticator := nil;
    SimpleAuthenticator1.UserNameKey := '';
    SimpleAuthenticator1.UserName := '';
    RESTRequest1.ResourceSuffix := '?ws_key=' + sWebkey;
    RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
    RESTRequest1.AddBody(Memo1.Text, ctTEXT_XML);
    RESTRequest1.Method := rmPost;
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
    Memo2.Lines.Clear;
    Memo2.Lines.Add(RESTResponse1.Content);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Clear;
      Memo2.Lines.Add('Exception class name = ' + E.ClassName);
      Memo2.Lines.Add('Exception message = ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
  Button8.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: `302` handling is ambiguous in the early HTTP protocol specs. Many web browsers and HTTP libraries react to a `302` response by repeating the same request as `GET` instead. Some don't. HTTP 1.1 documents this ambiguity, and defines `303` and `307` response codes to address the ambiguity to state when to switch to `GET` and when not to, but not everyone supports those response codes. Now, why Embarcadero would change their `302` handling from Seattle to Berlin is anyone's guess, but the new behavior is not technically wrong, just ambiguous. Can you change your REST server to send `307` instead?

Comment: If not, consider using Indy's `TIdHTTP` instead.  It has a `hoTreat302Like303` flag that is disabled by default so a new request sent in reaction to `302` will use the same HTTP method as the previous request.

Comment: @Remy-Lebeau, Thanks for the info. I have no control over the Server. I found out they changed the `TWinHTTPClient.DoProcessStatus`  procedure in `System.Net.HttpClient.Win`. They added code to change the POST for codes 301>303 in a GET. `Seattle` did not have that code.